# kdeconnect-app fails to startup

Tags: kde, ubuntu-studio, kde-connect

I am running UbuntuStudio 20.04 and up until recently was able to use KDEConnect without any issues.

Now KDEConnect does not start up. If I run kdeconnect-app on a terminal, I get the following error.

qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/main.qml:93 Cannot assign object of type "DevicesModel" to property of type "QAbstractItemModel*" as the former is neither the same as the latter nor a sub-class of it.

I have not done any changes apart from perhaps one regular system update.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no idea to fix it (tried to build from source but 20.04 haven't good lib version for qt5 Ext.) I'm running linuxmint distro with ubuntu 20.04.
I use redmi note 10 5g with kdeconnect.apk (googleplay)
A workaround solution is to not use kdeconnect-app.
Just use kdeconnect-cli and kdeconnect-indicator (gui-parameters).

**Some explanations:**

Due to a bug with official Debian package file:

```bsh
$ kdeconnect-app 
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/main.qml:93 Cannot assign object of type "DevicesModel" to property of type
"QAbstractItemModel*" as the former is neither the same as the latter nor a sub-class of it.
```

We can make it working in another way:

1. Thirst step is to put android device and Linux machine on the same network e.g. 10.42.10.1/24
2. On Android device, get from play-store the `kdeconnect` application.
3. Next, we have to, retrieve `kdeconnect` from distro's repository `$ sudo apt install kdeconnect`
4. Run: `$ kdeconnect-cli -l` which will list the connected devices and run the `kdeconnectd` daemon.
5. Then we can run: `$ kdeconnect-indicator` which will put a grey icon 'rectangle with [k] inside' in the task-bar from where you can configure the interaction with the android device.
6. Go back to Android and run `kdeconnect`, after that, you will ask for pairing with Linux, (you have to accept the request on Linux machine)
7. That all, you can try doing a copy to clipboard on Linux and paste the content to android, or somethings else.

[cli Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jFBa.jpg)

[configuration gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gabim.jpg)

Comment: Yes, kdeconnect-cli works without any problems so this is a good workaround till the devs  fix the issue. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this bug has already been reported in launchpad. It seems stalled because of dependency problems.

What we can do in the meantime is bring Ubuntu developers their attention to this issue by subscribing to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeconnect/+bug/1905341). If you are using GNOME, you can try [GSConnect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/).

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in KDEConnect 1.4.1 but latest version on apt is 1.4.0. [reference](https://invent.kde.org/network/kdeconnect-kde/-/commit/58a400af8cb51edf2f897929ebb9071387edd76d)

Until the package is updated, you should install KDEConnect from source. [source repository](https://invent.kde.org/network/kdeconnect-kde)